# how to add data dynamically to an array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add two element in an array. The first one is the key and the second is the value. But I want to add it dynamically. I want to do it like the following code:

```
$arr="";

for( $i=0;$i<20;$i++ ) {
    $arr[$i]=arr($i=>$i+1);
    array_push($arr[$i]);
}

print_r($arr);
```

But of course it don't work. Could anyone tell me how to do it ?

Comment: What you are trying to do `arr($i=>$i+1)`?

Comment: try this $arr[$i] = $i+1; and remove aray push not need

Comment: see this link :- http://uk3.php.net/array_push#83388 perfect for you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to do this:

```
$arr = array(); // use array() instead of empty string

for( $i=0; $i<20; $i++ ) {

    $arr[$i]= $i + 1;
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$arr` must be an array not string try this

```
$arr= array();
```

instead of

```
$arr="";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by all this, but you didn't really define the arrays correctly.

```
$arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) {
    $arr[$i] = $i + 1;
    array_push($arr[$i]);
}
print_r($arr);
```

Like answered above, you must use the `array()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) {
     $arr[$i] = $i+1;
}
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

## This is tested and working

```
<?php
$stack = array("");
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) {
array_push($stack, $i);
}
print_r($stack);
?>
```

this code will allow you to do what you request, unless I understood your requirement wrong?

Let me know if this is any help :)

If you are trying to create a numbered list, then use this instead:

```
<?php
$stack = array("0");
for($i=1;$i<20;$i++) {
array_push($stack, $i);
}
print_r($stack);
?>
```

Checkout the php manual: https://www.php.net/array_push

Josh.